# How many different ways can a pitcher throw $3$ pitches when warming up with $12$ pitches

Tags: combinatorics

A pitcher has three pitches, a fastball, a curveball, and a knuckleball. When warming up he wants to throw $3$ fastballs, $5$ curveballs, and $4$ knuckleballs. How many different ways can he throw those pitches when warming up

I am drawing a major blank. I feel like it is order doesn't matter without repetition but I'm lost as to which to use

Answer (score 1):

The fastballs are not distinguishable from each other, similarly with the curve balls and knuckle balls. The pitcher has to choose where he wants the fastballs, curve balls and knuckle balls in the 12 pitches. Hence there are $$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{5}\binom{4}{4}\quad\text{ways.}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard formula for *permutations with repetitions of indistinguishable objects.*

If n total objects have $k_1$ of one kind, $k_2$ of another, ......

number of permutations = $\dfrac{n!}{k_1!\cdot k_2!...}$

For your particular case, for instance, it would be $\dfrac{12!}{3!5!4!}$

It would be good to remember this as a general formula